# Calculador de letalidad

Tags: python

Intenté hacer una calculadora que según la cifra de muertos e infectados, calcule la letalidad total. En este caso, el problema que me encuentro es que cuando inserto los valores, debo tocar dos veces enter para que salte al siguiente input, y luego, que el resultado final me lo muestra con el numero entero, por ej: en vez de redondear a 0,4 me muestra 0,4285725824.

Como podria mejorar el codigo?

```
import math

print("Muertos totales")
muertos = input ()
input()
print("Infectados totales")
infectados = input()
input()

print ((int(muertos) / int(infectados)) * 100)
```

Comment: El problema parece solucionarse quitando los `input()` que están ahi sin hacer mas, ¿para qué los colocaste?

Comment: Gracias!! Los coloque porque pense que era necesario darle la orden de que ingrese un input y antes definirlo. La verdad que empece hace muy poquito, tu solucion fue acertada!

Como hago para redondear el numero del resultado final?

Comment: No conozco casi nada de Python, pero creo que tiene un método `round`

Comment: Muchas gracias igual por tu ayuda, muy amable de tu parte! Saludos

Comment: `input` es una función y cada llamada  hace que se espera a que el usuario ingrese algo por stdin y pulse `Enter` para terminar, retornando una cadena (`str`) con lo ingresado. `muertos = input()` llama a `input` y ésta espera a que el usuario ingrese algo y pulse `Enter`, luego retorna lo ingresado como una cadena y dicha cadena se asocia (asigna) a la variable `muertos`. La siguiente línea `input()` hace lo mismo pero su salida no se asocia a nada como comenta Aprendiz y la cadena retornada será recolectada por el GC.

Comment: Para redondear, tal como comenta Aprendiz, puedes usar `round` así:  `print(round((int(muertos) / int(infectados)) * 100, 1))` o puedes formatear la cadena dependiendo de lo que busques: `print(f"{(int(muertos) / int(infectados)) * 100:.1f}")`